# Peugeot partner 2011 diesel: p filter add level low

Tags: peugeot, warning-light, diesel-particulate-filter

Our Peugeot partner (2011) has a warning light and p filter add level low message. I can only find handbooks for new models online. Online there is some indication that  doing a motorway run to see if the filter clears then checking if the warning light is still on....others that the adblue levels need topping up and others again that eolys? Needs topping up at a garage. We had just topped up the diesel when the light came on. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make sure blue and eolys are full.  Yes, run engine at maximum rpm on an open highway, 80-130 kph, five times.

In addition, add Star Tron Diesel Additive.  It can be found [here](https://www.svb24.com/en/star-brite-startron-diesel-additive.html) and elsewhere.  Use 10x the recommended dose on the bottle, the excess will go through the exhaust and clean the p filter.  It is impossible to use too much, contains no solvents, and will not damage any parts.  It contains carbon dissolving enzymes, used worldwide in autos and industry, that work with any other additive.

Use a 2-3x dosage with every fill-up to prevent the problem in the future.